# safeArgs or safeArgs.kotlin in Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I was trying to implement safeArgs in Navigation, and I saw the following in the documentation
You must also apply one of two available plugins.

> To generate Java code suitable for Java or mixed Java and Kotlin modules, add this line to your app or module's build.gradle file:
>
> apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
>
> Alternatively, to generate Kotlin code suitable for Kotlin-only modules add:
>
> apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

My project is entirely written in Kotlin, however there are libraries such as Retrofit and Glide that were written in Java.

> Should I apply safeArgs given the libraries were written in Java and the code I wrote was written in Kotlin, resulting in a mixed modules?

Comment: what have you used? have you had any issues so far?

Comment: I used safeArgs at the end, however I cannot use byNavArgs() because I did not use safeArgs.kotlin

Comment: You can use the Kotlin one. The thing that matters is the code where you use the args, not if you have some Java code elsewhere.